# Angularjs JSON content inside ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ng-view

I am stuck in calling json text inside the ng-view. In normal HTML **{{profile.experience}}** this works perfect fine. fetching the data from json.
But since I have add the ng-view **{{profile.experience}}** is unable to fetch the data from json.

```
<div class="profile-snapshot">                          
    <ul>
        <li><span>Experience:</span><p> {{profile.experience}}</p></li>
        <li><span>Education:</span><p> {{profile.education}}</p></li>
        <li><span>Designation:</span><p>{{profile.designation}}</p></li>
        <li><span>Age:</span><p>32</p></li>
        <li><span>City:</span><p>Thane</p></li>                             
    </ul>
</div>
```

This what my json look like

```
 {
"experience": "Experience 8 Years asda s",
"education": "MBA, B.COM",
"designation": "UX Designer, Front End Developer"
}
```

this is what my angularjs code looks like

```
var accord = angular.module('accord', []);
var profileLoad = angular.module('profileLoad',[]);
var app2 = angular.module('main-app', ['accord','profileLoad','ngRoute']);

profileLoad.controller('profileCntrl', function($scope, $http){
'use strict';
$http.get('candidateProfile.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.profile = data;
    });
});


app2.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'profile.html',
        controller: 'StudentController'
    })
    .when('/viewStudents', {
        templateUrl: 'profile-edit.html',
        controller: 'StudentController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

can anyone please help me in fetching the json data inside ng-view?

Comment: try to tell angular you updated the data with `$scope.$apply()` inside the `success` block.

Comment: can you please elaborate it more? if you could please

Comment: `$scope.apply()` tells angular that a model update has occurred and it needs to update the views bound to that scope. Try to call `$scope.$apply()` in your `success` function, after you update `$scope.profile`

Comment: thanks @MuliYulzary tried. but no luck. Think I should upload a  http://plnkr.co/

Comment: Go for it, I'll have a look.

Comment: @MuliYulzary http://plnkr.co/edit/K1bM3mBOVUiSDBNOPHCY?p=preview Here is the plnkr. it is bit messy, my head is swinging now after full night awake in cracking up the code. I will be greatfull to you.

Comment: this is all I managed to salvage: please fix the rest. your plunkr still doesn't work. you're missing `StudentControl` http://plnkr.co/edit/dMr8mlvbFWg0NXqgW2Lh

Comment: all right thanks for the efforts

Comment: @AshishPhadale, please read more about `AngularJS` and `ngRoute` they have a very good documentations. Btw here's what I've got, study it: http://plnkr.co/edit/AH4G1ywfKuR9zrNtyJtB?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot @LekzFlores cheers. And thanks for the advice, I will definitely read more about AngularJs and ngRoute

Comment: @AshishPhadale,Enjoy! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was already applying the controller. Only thing I needed to do is remove the         **controller: 'StudentController'**.

That solved the problem for me.

I really appreciate the quick reply from the members here.

Cheers guys

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, I think

```
profileLoad.controller('profileCntrl', function($scope, $http){ ... }
```

should be

```
profileLoad.controller('StudentController', function($scope, $http){ ... }
```

You're retrieving the data in a controller that's not mapped to a template in `$routeProvider`.

Also, you should put your `$http.get` in a service and inject that service into your controller. Keep your concerns separated and your controllers lean.

Comment: can any1 please help in this?